# Function Not Returning Screen Res Values

Tags: ms-access, vba

Function works and gets screen resolution.  But when I try to pass back to sub fun_x and fun_y are coming back empty. Why?

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

Dim sub_x As Long, sub_y As Long

ScreenRes fun_x:=sub_x, fun_y:=sub_y

Debug.Print sub_x, sub_y, fun_x, fun_y

End Sub
```

---

MODULE NAME:MOD_GET_RES

```
Option Compare Database

Declare Function GetSystemMetrics32 Lib "User32" _
Alias "GetSystemMetrics" (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long

Function ScreenRes(ByVal fun_x As Long, ByVal fun_y As Long)

fun_x = GetSystemMetrics32(0) ' width in points
fun_y = GetSystemMetrics32(1) ' height in points

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've passed the function arguments `ByVal`(ue) so when it returns, only a copy is modified. Use `ByRef`(erence) implicitly or not to make it work:

```
Function ScreenRes(fun_x As Long, fun_y As Long)
```

You could also make `GetSystemMetrics32` (why are you using a longer alias?) private.

EDIT: below are some more explanations from a minimal example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CantChange(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)
    'When this gets called, a copy of the original variables
    'is pushed on the stack.
    a = a * 2 'The copy is altered.
    b = b + 1
    'When leaving this Sub, the copy is discarded.
End Sub

'exactly the same Sub procedure... except for the (implicit) ByRef
Sub Change(a As Integer, b As Integer)
    'When this gets called, references
    '(i.e. the location of the original variable)
    'are pushed on the stack.
    a = a * 2 'The original variable is altered.
    b = b + 1
End Sub

Sub Test()
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer
    a = 1
    b = 5
    Debug.Print "before:", a, b
    CantChange a, b
    Debug.Print "unchanged:", a, b
    Change a, b
    Debug.Print "changed:", a, b
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked but I do not understand why.  I guess I need to do some reading on the difference.

Comment: I've added a simple example, I hope it's clearer now ;)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to put that together.  Very helpful to understand WHY rather than how.